# Problem running a docker container by specifying sh or bash for that image on a vm instance

Tags: bash, docker, virtual-machine, sh

I have vm environment which i have created using Microsoft azure cloud. I have installed docker in this vm. I can run docker image without specifying the any terminal like sh or bash and it is working. when i say 
docker run -it hello-world --->> it works

docker run -it hello-world sh ---->>> it don't works.
actually i am working on a networking tool kathara where i have to start a virtual lab using many pcs and router and then i have to specify the terminal for them when i want to open any pc or router.
this is the actual error i am getting wheni start conatiner 
"**critical - 400 client error: bad request ("oci runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown")**"

Answer (score 1):

`docker run -it hello-world` runs the container's default command: `./hello`. That works, because that's what the container is designed to do.

`docker run -it hello-world /bin/bash` tries to run `/bin/bash` inside the container. That doesn't work, because that's *not* what the container is designed to do. That command does not exist within the container.

If you want to run `/bin/bash`, choose a container that has `/bin/bash`.

This is even suggested in the output of `docker run -it hello-world`:

> To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
>
> > $ docker run -it ubuntu bash